# Mediation analysis with mma() package in R error: Error in Anova.III.LR.glm(mod, singular.ok = singular.ok)

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to run a mediation analysis with multiple parallel mediators using the mma() package in R. However, every time I try to run my code below, I am getting an error:

```
library(mma)

vcsqi <- as.data.frame(vcsqi.dci)
vcsqi <- vcsqi[, c("predmort", "age", "male", "bmi")]
vcsqi <- na.omit(vcsqi)
x = vcsqi
y = vcsqi[,"predmort"]
pred = vcsqi[,"bmi"]

test <- mma(x, y, pred=pred, mediator=c(2,3))
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Error in Anova.III.LR.glm(mod, singular.ok = singular.ok) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

I understand that this error typically suggests multicollinearity or an issue with linearly dependent variables. However, I am not sure how to address this issue in the context of the mma() function or the data I am working with. I've checked for multicollinearity among my variables and didn't find any high correlations that would cause concern.

I am interested in examining the mediation effects of 'age' and 'male' on the relationship between 'bmi' (predictor) and 'predmort' (outcome).

Could anyone provide insight into why I might be receiving this error and how I might resolve it to successfully run my mediation analysis? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Example of how the code should be running:

```
data("weight_behavior")
x=weight_behavior[,c(2,4:14)]
pred=weight_behavior[,3]
y=weight_behavior[,15]
temp.b.b.glm<-mma(x,y,pred=pred,contmed=c(7:9,11:12),binmed=c(6,10),binref=c(1,1),
catmed=5,catref=1,predref="M",alpha=0.4,alpha2=0.4,n=2,n2=2)
```

Output

```
temp.b.b.glm
For Categorical Exposure(s): [1] "pred"

 MMA Analysis: Estimated Mediation Effects Using GLM
$ie
     y1.all y1.exercises y1.sweat y1.sports
pred  0.116      -0.0286   0.0118     0.165

$te
y1.pred 
  0.604 

$de
y1.pred 
  0.488
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Did you leave the outcome variable in the `x` value?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This is my first post on StackOverflow so am not very familiar with the protocol: